# ASP.Net - Files and folders upload plugins

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

Is there any tools or plugins to upload folders as well as multiple files to integrate with my asp.net website.
-folder-upload
-multiple-file-upload
-fast-upload

Comment: check this plugin
[File Upload Plugin Demo](http://www.aspsnippets.com/articles/select-and-upload-multiple-files-gmail-style-using-jquery-and-asp.net.aspx)

Comment: Thank you Amit. But is it good to use java applet for folder upload? I found one java applet which has all the features i need.